# Unity: using yield waitforseconds more than once

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

The idea is to create a delay every 2 seconds for **Regenerate()**, so I can give 2 seconds for the player to catch the scoreObject, otherwise it teleports to the random coordinates.

The problem is that after the first cycle, `yield WaitForSeconds(2);` gets ignored, making the scoreObject untouchable.

```
#pragma strict

public var scoreObject : GameObject;

function Update () {
    Regenerate();
}

function Regenerate () {
    yield WaitForSeconds(2);
    scoreObject.transform.position.z = Random.Range(-6.0, 6.0);
    scoreObject.transform.position.x = Random.Range(-4.5, 4.5);
}
```

Is there any way to get rid of this issue? I want this wait to work every time Regenerate() is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are starting new `WaitForSeconds` on every frame. So after 2 seconds there is one wait ending on almost every frame. You can fix this with boolean variable, by doing `Regenerate()` only when it is `true` and setting it to `false` while waiting.

```
#pragma strict

public var scoreObject : GameObject;

var doRegenerate = true;

function Update () {
    if(doRegenerate) {
        Regenerate();
    }
}

function Regenerate () {
    doRegenerate = false;
    yield WaitForSeconds(2);
    doRegenerate = true;
    scoreObject.transform.position.z = Random.Range(-6.0, 6.0);
    scoreObject.transform.position.x = Random.Range(-4.5, 4.5);
}
```